# Drop similar word in a tuple list

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this(phrase, score) : [('center', 1), ('car center', 2), ('rental car', 1.5), ('car center', 2), ('rental car center', 3), ('weather', 4), ... ...]

I want to eliminate the repeating phrase by rule:

If the one phrase contains words that ALL shown up in another phrase, drop the one with lowest score. 
for example, 'car center' = set(car, center) is a subset of 'rental car center' = set(rental, car, center)
if two sets only intersect but not subset of the other, I don't drop either one of them.

I couldn't think of a better way other than running a nested for loop and pop the item during the loop. I also consider using set and intersection, but i need to compare all two combinations, is there any way i won't miss any pair of the combination and efficiently do this?

Output is a list of phrase score tuple, so people won't find pairs that have two phrases with one of them being subset of the other.

Comment: What's your expected output for the example? Do you drop the lowest of all the ones that are contained in another?

Comment: Now, extend that thought to 3-word and 4-word phrases.  How would you find that "airport rental car center" was found in "rental car center at Laguardia international airport"?  You're asking for an open-ended algorithm and design, which is too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  re-take the intro tour.  When you're ready to ask about a *specific* programming problem, post your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and we'll help.

Comment: @Prune "airport rental car center" and "rental car center at Laguardia international airport" only intersect at ''rental car center", but they are not subset of each one another so i won't drop either of them.

Comment: @rasaar output would be a list of tuple (phrase, score), but there won't exist a pair hat have two phrases with one of them being subset of the other.

Comment: Your post says "If the one phrase contains words that ALL shown up in another phrase".  The case I posted has that property.  If that's *not* what you want, if it's inclusion of the entire phrase, then please update your question to reflect it ... and you should be able to develop a straightforward solution to the problem.

Comment: Each word of "airport rental car center" *is* in "rental car center at Laguardia international airport".

Comment: Please provide a clear and complete explanation of the operation, as well as some representative input and the corresponding output.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along these lines:

```
a=[('center', 1), ('car center', 2), ('rental car', 1.5), ('car center', 2), ('rental car center', 3), ('weather', 4)]

d = {}
keys_to_remove =set()
for i in a:
    keys = d.keys()

    for key in list(d.keys()):
        if (i[0] in key):
            d[key] = max(i[1],d.get(key))
        elif key in i[0]:
            d[i[0]]=max(i[1],d.get(key))
            keys_to_remove.add(key)
        else:
            d[i[0]]=i[1]

    else:
        d[i[0]]=i[1]
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k not in keys_to_remove}
```